# iOS - RSS reader library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rss, rss-reader

Is there a good RSS reader library for iOS/Objective C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any API's that exist for parsing RSS specifically (there may be some I don't know of), but an XML parser should do just fine for what you are looking for.

I use TouchXML for most of my projects: https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML

Here is an article that will help you pick out the correct XML parser for your project: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Comment: having just had the need to parse RSS / XML feed in an Obj-C iOS app, I went with NSXMLParse as noted in the raywenderlich link above. Use of NSXMLParse requires that you build your own structure from the XML data. 

[Apple NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxmlparser?language=objc)

Answer (score 9):

Might want to check out this: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser